# AngularJS ng-init does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-http, ng-init

When i go to list.html right after loading the page it doesnt show me the list. I need to go to form.html first and then back to list.html and then it gives me the list. When i had $http functions in controller it worked as i wanted but now that they are in service they dont work like before.

app.js

```
app.service("dataservice", function($http){

    var list = [{}];

    this.get = function(){
        $http.get("harjoitus22/backend.php").success(function(response){
            list = response;
        });
    };

    this.save = function(newcontact){

        $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'harjoitus22/backend.php',
            data: newcontact,
            header: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'
        }).success(function(response){
            list = response;            
        });         
    }; 

    this.give = function(){
        return list;
    };
});

app.controller("mainController", function($scope, $location, dataservice){

    $scope.save = function(){    
        dataservice.save($scope.newcontact);
        $scope.newcontact = {};
        $location.path("/list");
        $scope.list = dataservice.give();
    };

    $scope.get = function(){
        dataservice.get();
        $scope.list = dataservice.give();
    };
});
```

list.html

```
    <tbody ng-init="get()">
        <tr ng-repeat="object in list">
            <td>{{object.nimi}}</td>
            <td>{{object.email}}</td>
            <td>{{object.ruoka}}</td>
            <td>{{object.sauna}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$http` call works asynchronously, when you call it, It will not give you response on next line execution. To keep eye on that ajax you should take use of `promise` return by `$http` method.

For achieving the same you need to return promise object from the service `get` method (`$http` methods does return's promise object, which helps you to execute your code by putting up in its `.then` function's).

**Service**

```
this.get = function(){
    return $http.get("harjoitus22/backend.php").then(function(res){
        list = res.data;
    });
};
```

**Controller**

```
dataservice.get().then(function(){
   $scope.list = dataservice.give();
});
```

Comment: Not "could", but "should" hehe